# How to add a blinking cursor to a input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input tag that is read only, and I need to add a blinking cursor (the reasons i because I need to disable the virtual keyboard on android user select the field).
It needs to work in the latest version of chrome, CSS or JS solutions are fine. Any ideas? Thanks!

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="0" readonly="true">
```

Comment: post your css to

Comment: This is a questionable idea. you're breaking the mental model of the UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is read only the cursor wont show up, I don't know why you want a cursor in a read only input but if you do you can use javascript to not allow them to enter and autofocus the input to show the cursor.

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="0"  autofocus onkeydown="return false">
```

Comment: I need the read only property in order to disable the virtual keyboard on android

Comment: Does the return false not work on android? It should disable them from entering any text, but still display the cursor.

Comment: Again. Why on earth would you want that? That's only tricking your users into thinking that this is a clickable item and that you can enter text. There is no need for a blinking cursor if you cant enter text.

Comment: I agree Tim but my examples seem to do what they asked.